# Angular 6 - ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined, While showing the output

Tags: html, json, typescript, angular6

I'm getting following error in Angular 6. I'm showing json data which were return from the database. When I do a console.log in the .ts file, it shows me the whole array with data. Even this gives an error saying firstName is undefined, it displays the correct firstName in the relevant place. Even if I use `*ngIf="user.firstName"` the error remains same. If I put another attribute in the array before the `user.firstName`, the error is given to that attribute and display the correct output.

Eg :

```
{{user.firstName}}
```

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '**firstName**' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

```
{{user.lastName}}
{{user.firstName}}
```

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '**lastName**' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]
The error will shows only for lastName in here.

May I know the reason for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the safe navigation operator ?.

```
{{user?.lastName}}
{{user?.firstName}}
```

It is user that is undefined.

You could also use

```
<ng-container *ngIf="user">
    {{user.lastName}}
    {{user.firstName}}
<ng-container>
```

Comment: How come the data is displayed while user is undefined. I'm new to angular and trying to figure things out. Thank you

Comment: I cannot see your code that sets user but I am going to assume that you make a http request to get the user. When you load the page, user is undefined and when the http request if complete you assign the result to user. This is when you go from user being undefined to having a value.

Comment: If you set user to an empty object user = {};

Comment: I'm defining user as 

user: User;

which is an object of User Class. How can I set it to empty

Comment: user = { lastName: null; firstName: null };